# Trying to return the char in the middle of an input (char array) gives "segmentation fault (core dumped)"?

Tags: c

In a nutshell, I have to be able to return the character in the middle of an input (char array) for part of our first C assignment. What I have so far, however, is code that returns "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I read into this a little bit, and learned that essentially I may be trying to access/modify data that is "not available to me", so-to-speak. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char input[30];
int inputLen;
char midChar;

int main()
{
    printf("Type in some text, and the press the Return/Enter key: ");
    fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
    printf("\nYour input: %s",input);
    inputLen = strlen(input)-1;
    printf("Length of your input is %d characters.",inputLen);

    if((inputLen % 2) == 0) {
        midChar = input[(inputLen/2)+1];    // >>> PROBLEM HERE <<<
    }
    else {
        midChar = input[((inputLen+1)/2)+1];    // >>> PROBLEM HERE <<<
    }
    printf("%s",midChar);
    return 0;
}
```

The two lines with `>>> PROBLEM HERE <<<` are the lines which I believe I've narrowed down to be the source of the problem.

**Please Note:** I have taken an introductory class in Java, and last semester took a class half-devoted to MATLAB, so I do have a *little* bit of programming intuition -- However, I am a 100% beginner in C, so I would appreciate some clear elaboration behind any help you guys may offer. I am not familiar with most functions/syntax unique to C, so I'm sure there will be cringe-worthy lines of code above for those well-versed in this language. If this is the case, feel free to include any other tips in your answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're printing a `char` with `%s`, so the program is treating your input as a pointer (to a char array). It's not a valid such thing.

You meant `%c` for a single character.

Your compiler should tell you about this. Turn warnings on!

Comment: `-Wall` all the time!

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Answer (score 2):

A late addition:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  // This will be the default value if a string of length 0 is entered
  char midChar = 0;
  int inputLen;
  int bufferLen = 31;
  char* input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferLen);

  printf("Type in some text, and the press the Return/Enter key: ");
  fgets(input, bufferLen, stdin);

  printf("\nYour input: %s", input);
  inputLen = strlen(input);

  if (input[inputLen - 1] == '\n') {
    inputLen--;  // ignore new line character
  }
  printf("Length of your input is %d characters.\n", inputLen);

  if (inputLen > 0) {
    midChar = input[inputLen / 2];  // take right of middle for even number
  }

  printf("%c\n", midChar);
  return 0;
}
```

In your previous post you used `sizeof(input)` which is not recommended for reasons described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503098/sizeof-a-static-array-in-c). It is better practice to hold the length of the array in a separate variable, here `bufferLen`.

Also the use of [global variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable#C_and_C++) here `input` `inputLen` `midChar` is generally discouraged as they lead to unexpected behaviour during linking and make program flow harder to understand.

I initialised the memory for the buffer dynamically so the `bufferLen` could be changed in the program.

When computing the length of the input one must consider the newline character `\n` which is retained if a small enough string is entered but not if the entered string exceeds the `bufferLen`.

For strings with even lengths I arbitrarily took the character to the right. The `inputLen` zero case is also handled.

This whole answer is only an addition to the first one which already found the bug correctly, because I was late to the party.

Answer (score 1):

Other than print char problem, I think there is also a problem at where you indicated.

ex. if input string is `abc`, inputLen will be 3, midchar index should be at 1 since array index in C start from 0. However ((inputLen+1)/2)+1 gives 3. This probably won't directly cause the segfault but will give wrong answer.

You can replace

```
    if((inputLen % 2) == 0) {
        midChar = input[(inputLen/2)+1];    // >>> PROBLEM HERE <<<
    }
    else {
        midChar = input[((inputLen+1)/2)+1];    // >>> PROBLEM HERE <<<
    }
```

with

```
midChar = input[inputLen/2];
```

since C will truncate when doing integer division.

```
 a    b    c -> 3/2 = 1
[0]  [1]  [2]
```

```
 a    b    c    d  -> 4/2 = 2
[0]  [1]  [2]  [3]
```

Other than that, you also need to make sure the inputLen is not 0

Answer (score 1):

Although "pretty lady" (@LightnessRasesInOrbit) up here is correct, let me explain what is happening when you do this:

```
printf("%s\n", charVar);
```

or this:

```
printf("%s\n", intVar);
```

or this:

```
printf("%s\n", floatVar);
```

Or when you print things using `pritnf()` with `%s`. You have to understand how does `printf ("%s", string)` work!! So when `printf` gets `%s` it looks for C string or in other words, character array terminated with '\0'. If it does not '\0' it will segfault. In depth, `printf()` works like this:

```
char name[4];
printf("Hello ", name);
```

now printf does following:

1. gets the size of 1st variable ("Hello")
2. gets the size of 2nd variable (name) How? Simple by this loop:

   ```
   int varSize;
   for (varSize = 0; varSize != '\0'; ++varSize);
   ```
3. moves "Hello" into buffer
4. Determine the size of second parameter. How, by doing this:
5. does following

   ```
   if ("%d")
        // read intVar and attach it to the buffer
   if ("%f")
        // read floatVar and attach it to the buffer
   if ("%s")
       for (int i = 0; stringVar[i] != '\0'; ++i)
           // push each char into the buffer
   ```

So I hope you see what is happening if one of `for()` loops does not find '\0' character. If you do good if you don't well it continues reading through until it segfaults.

NOTE:
This is oversimplified pseudo code on how `printf()` works and is not actual implementation, this is only for OP to understand what is going on.